# How to merge tables in SQL server that have a different column headers that map to a common description?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, dynamic-sql

I have multiple tables that I want to merge into a single table. The tables represent the same data but have different column headers because they came from multiple sources. For example, in Table1 we will have "Tel_Nbr", in Table2 "TelNumber" and in Table3 "TelNum" etc.. Instead of renaming the columns in each table and for better maintainability, I figured I could create a mapping table where I map each column header name from each table to the common description in the final output table as shown below. However, I am not exactly sure that's the best approach because I am using the table names in the mapping table, and I cant figure out the query syntax.

Table1

```
First_Name | Last_Name | Telephone_Number
-----------------------------------------
John       | Smith     | 3333
Michael    | Taylor    | 4444
```

Table2

```
F_Name     | L_Name    | Tel_Nbr
--------------------------------
Joe        | Lopez     | 5555
Rachel     | Moore     | 6666
```

Mapping_Table

```
Output       | Table1           | Table2
----------------------------------------
FirstName    | First_Name       | F_Name
LastName     | Last_Name        | L_Name
TelephoneNbr | Telephone_Number | Tel_Nbr
```

Output

```
    FirstName  | LastName  | TelephoneNbr
    -----------------------------------------
    John       | Smith     | 3333
    Michael    | Taylor    | 4444
    Joe        | Lopez     | 5555
    Rachel     | Moore     | 6666
```

Comment: If you want to change the headings of columns, you will need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff points out, what you ask for requires dynamic SQL. That is, build a query string from the content of  `mapping_table`, then executing it.

Consider:

```
declare 
    @q1 nvarchar(max), 
    @q2 nvarchar(max), 
    @q nvarchar(max)
;

select 
    @q1 = string_agg(table1 + ' as ' + output, ', ') within group(order by output),
    @q2 = string_agg(table2, ', ') within group(order by output)
from mapping_table;

set @q = 'select ' + @q1 + N' from table1 union all select ' + @q2 + ' from table2'

--debug
select @q;

-- execute
EXEC sp_executesql @q;
```

For your sample data, the generated query is (I added line breaks and indentation for better readibility):

```
select First_Name as FirstName, Last_Name as LastName, Telephone_Number as TelephoneNbr 
from table1 
union all 
select F_Name, L_Name, Tel_Nbr from table2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cba29b85162d943ba07ea9ed5ec6020c)**